# GitHub problem: Git pushes to master branch, not main and the two can't be merged

Tags: git, github, branching-and-merging

Every time I create a repository on GitHub and push my files it creates two branches, the main branch and the master branch.
All the changes go to the master branch and when I go to 'Compare and pull request' it says there's nothing to compare, so there's no way to push to the main branch.

These are the steps I took:
Go to GitHub, create a repository.
Go to my folder and run `git init`,`git add .`, `git commit -m "first commit"`, `git remote add origin my@repository`, and `git push -u origin master`
Now I know that I need to create a main branch, so I also run `git checkout -b main`, which runs successfully, but then, when I run `git push --set-upstream origin main`, it throws an error:

```
 ! [rejected]          main -> main (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@github.com:myuser/myrepo.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

I also run `git pull` but it says it's already up to date.
Also on main branch I run `git merge master`, but it gives the message: `Already up to date`, and vice versa, from master branch tried to merge the main one (just to check) and the same message is given.
I've also tried runing `git push -u origin main`, which gives the following error:

```
error: src refspec main does not match any
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@github.com:myuser/myrepo.git'
```

Note that I also tried all those commands in different order as well, with the same errors as a result.

What can I do to solve this?

Comment: are you working with forks?

Comment: Unclear. Did you want the default branch to be master or main? If main, why do you not follow GitHub instructions? If master, why create main?

Comment: “Now I know, I need to create a main branch” No you don’t. Why don’t you just stop after the initial push?

Comment: @matt there's no main branch in the terminal through the whole process, only master is created, but on github there's only main, so yes.

Comment: @matt On github they changed it so the main branch is now called main. I want to push to the default branch on github, which is main. Followed github instructions, as explained above, but it leads to this situation

Comment: @x-rw No, just from local repository

Comment: But you _didn't_ follow the GitHub instructions. You pushed master, which is not what they tell you to do, and you didn't `git branch -M main`, which is what they _do_ tell you to do.

Answer (score 28):

The whole question is based on a misconception, which is summarized in your first sentence:

> Every time I create a repository on github and push my files it creates two branches, the main branch and the master branch

No. That is not something "it" does. That is something *you* are doing. And if you don't want that to happen, then *don't do it.* To avoid doing it, you need to think first, before acting. You need to **decide** how you want things to be, and only then you take action to make it so.

Let's talk about the **decisions** you need to make, and how to make them come true.

---

First of all, when you create the repo at GitHub, you need to **decide** whether it is to be completely empty or whether it should have any initial elements such as a README.

*I like my repo to be completely empty*. In that case it has *no branches at all*. Everything is thus up to you at the local end. GitHub provides perfectly clear instructions as to what to do at this point. Let's say you have an existing local repo, as you have created:

```
git init
git add .
git commit -m "first commit"
```

Now *your* default branch is `master`. So you have to **decide** now whether to keep that or change it to `main`. Either way, *do not push* until you have made a decision!

If you decide to *keep it as `master`*, then just add the remote and push, exactly as you did:

```
git remote add origin my@repository
git push -u origin master
```

Now *stop*. You say:

> I need to create a main branch

No, you don't! You have made `master` your primary branch, so just keep using it as the primary branch.

On the other hand if you decide *you want `main` as your primary branch*, then follow the instructions that GitHub gives you:

```
git remote add origin my@repository
git branch -M main
git push -u origin main
```

And again, *stop*.

Either way, you have pushed just *one* initial branch, *either* `master` *or* `main`. But do *not* do what *you* are doing, namely, push `master` and then mysteriously change your mind and decide you wish it had been `main`. That is how you've gotten yourself into an unnecessary tangle.

---

For the sake of completeness, let's say you initially decide when you create the GitHub repo that *you want it to have initial contents*. That is a bad decision if you are going to be starting with `git init` at the local end, and GitHub tells you so in no uncertain terms. But let's proceed with this alternate scenario anyway.

Suppose you elect to start your GitHub repo with a Readme. Okay, so *now* the GitHub repo *does* have an initial branch, and it *is* `main`. So now once again you have two choices about what to do on your local machine: you must **decide** whether to start locally with an empty copy of this same GitHub repo, or whether to start locally with a repo that you may already have.

If you decide to *start empty locally*, then do *not* say `git init`. Say `git clone` and clone the remote GitHub repo to your local machine. *This is far and away the best choice in this situation.*

But let's say you don't do that. Let's say you decide *create a separate local repo from scratch.* For instance, you do this:

```
 $ git init what; cd $_
 $ echo howdy > testing.txt; git add .; git commit -minitial
 $ git remote add origin my@repository
```

Now you are in a serious mess, because:

- Your remote repo and your local repo *both* have stuff that the other doesn't have.
- Your local repo has `master` but your remote repo has `main`.

How are you going to push this? Well, I'm going to assume that you accept the notion, imposed on you now by GitHub, that you should use `main` as your main branch. So here is what you do:

```
$ git branch -M main
$ git pull origin main --allow-unrelated
$ git push -u origin main
```

Now you have folded your remote repo and your local repo together with the same branch and the same contents.

Comment: In gitlab, even if I unselect the "create readme" to open an empty branchless project, the branch "main" is automatically created. any idea?

Comment: The `main` branch is created in theory as the remote head, but that doesn't matter unless commits are added to it. Without commits, it is an "unborn branch". See my https://www.biteinteractive.com/of-git-and-github-master-and-main/ — it's about GitHub but the key points are the same.

Answer (score -1):

Apply these commands:

```
git rebase master

git add theFiles

git commit -m "your commit"

git push -f
```

Comment: Can you add some explanation about what this does?