# git pull from a listed branch (master) is not working but works with a brach that is not listed (main)

Tags: git, git-pull

```
> (base)user@files % git branch
* master

> (base) user@files % git pull origin master
fatal: couldn't find remote ref master

> (base) user@files % git pull origin main
From https://github.com/name/teamstuff
 * branch            main       -> FETCH_HEAD
Already up to date.
```

Comment: What is your question, please?

Comment: @matt Well, I'm sure the question is "What the hell is going on and where are my branches?" ;-)

Comment: Yes, it sounds like we might be in the situation I describe in the second half of my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65924087/github-problem-git-pushes-to-master-branch-not-main-and-cant-merge-the-two/65925862#65925862 But it's hard to be sure without the OP saying what the surprise / goal is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Phade160,
You are using `git branch` to list the branches. This will list only local branches. So, In the local, you have only one branch, i.e, master.

If you want to list the remote branches, please use the below command. The below command will list all the remote branches. I am sure, After you run this command, you would see, a branch named `main` is listed.

> git branch -r

Now, As to answer, why **git pull origin main** works is, you have a remote branch named as **main** and you are trying to pull from that branch, which is valid.

Now, As to answer, why **git pull origin master** doesn't work is, you don't have a remote branch named as **master**. Which means, You are trying to pull from a remote branch which doesn't exist.

Please note, Going further, All the new repositories will have a default branch named as **main** and not **master**.

Hope, I answered your question!. Happy Coding!